# Is there a way to access fonts icons from html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, graph, html5-canvas

I am new to html5 canvas.

I need to display fonticons ([fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)) as images.
Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed possible, though it is a bit cumbersome.

Since Canvas will draw with a fallback font if the actual font it not yet ready, and since fonts are lazy loaded you will need to hold of rendering until the font is ready. This should be possible using something like Google/Typekit's Web Font Loader (https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader)

Once the font is ready, you can draw it in canvas as any other string, something like

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '48px FontAwesome';
  ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(61449), 10, 50);
```

The biggest challenge is that you have to remap all the symbols in Font Awesome, the their JavaScript char representations.

**Edit:**

This can actually be done using the name, by calcualting CSS rules

```
getFAChar = function (name) {
    var elm = document.createElement('i');
    elm.className = 'fa fa-' + name;
    elm.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(elm);
    var content = window.getComputedStyle(
        elm, ':before'
    ).getPropertyValue('content')
    document.body.removeChild(elm);
    return content;
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '48px FontAwesome';
  ctx.fillText(getFAChar('bed'), 10, 50)
```

**Edit:**

To improve performance, FA icons should be cached, especially if the Canvas is redrawn often (adding and removing a lot of DOM elements is not a good idea when trying to reach 60 fps)

```
var FontAwesome = (function () {
    var me = {},
        FACache = {};

    function find (name) {
        var elm = document.createElement('i');
        elm.className = 'fa fa-' + name;
        elm.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(elm);
        var content = window.getComputedStyle(
            elm, ':before'
        ).getPropertyValue('content')
        document.body.removeChild(elm);
        return content;
    };

    me.get = function (name) {
        if (!!FACache[name]) return FACache[name];
        var c = find(name);
        FACache[name] = c;
        return c;
    };
    return me;
}());

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '48px FontAwesome';
  ctx.fillText(FontAwesome.get('bed'), 10, 50);
```

**Edit**

Complete example using deferred render, auto css injection and mapping of css chars, though only tested in Chrome (Uses font loading API and Promises without polyfill)

```js
var FontAwesome = function () {
 return new Promise(function (done, failed) {
  var me = {},
   FACache = {};

  function find (name) {
   var elm = document.createElement('i');
   elm.className = 'fa fa-' + name;
   elm.style.display = 'none';
   document.body.appendChild(elm);
   var content = window.getComputedStyle(
    elm, ':before'
   ).getPropertyValue('content')
   document.body.removeChild(elm);
   return content;
  };

  me.get = function (name) {
   if (!!FACache[name]) return FACache[name];
   var c = find(name)[1];
   FACache[name] = c;
   return c;
  };
  
  (function() {
   var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
   l.onload = function () {
    document.fonts.load('10px FontAwesome')
     .then(function (e) { done(me); })
     .catch(failed);
   }
   l.href = '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';
   var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
  }());
 });
};

FontAwesome()
.then(function (fa) {
    // All set, and ready to render!
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        ctx.font = '48px FontAwesome';
        ctx.fillText(fa.get('bed'), 10, 50);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. One last comment:
As the example where it calculates the Font Awesome char from CSS rules actually creates elements and removes them for each time, it might be a good idea to cache those characters, if the canvas is going to be redrawn often.

I will update the above example with a simple version

Comment: Wow, this is great it just clarify every thing. thanks once more