# How to render icon fonts on HTML canvas and Material Design icon fonts in particular?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, icons

[This wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30708321/144088) details how to include icons from FontAwesome in a HTML canvas. Adapting the code for icon font from Material Design doesn't work, however. All the code is the same except for replacing FontAwesome values for Material Design values.

Code below.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Crashalot/pen/dyyEPWV

1) How do you incorporate icons from Material Design in HTML canvas?

2) How do you incorporate icons from any icon font (e.g., https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-icons)?

```
var FontAwesome = function () {
    return new Promise(function (done, failed) {
        var me = {},
            FACache = {};

        function find (name) {
            var elm = document.createElement('i');
            elm.className = 'fa fa-' + name;
            elm.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(elm);
            var content = window.getComputedStyle(
                elm, ':before'
            ).getPropertyValue('content')
            document.body.removeChild(elm);
            return content;
        };

        me.get = function (name) {
            if (!!FACache[name]) return FACache[name];
            var c = find(name)[1];
            FACache[name] = c;
            return c;
        };

        (function() {
            var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
            l.onload = function () {
                document.fonts.load('10px Material Icons')
                    .then(function (e) { done(me); })
                    .catch(failed);
            }
            l.href = '//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
            var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
        }());
    });
};

FontAwesome()
.then(function (fa) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    const x = canvas.width / 2;
    const y = canvas.height / 2;

    // All set, and ready to render!
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.font = '400px Material Icons';
        ctx.fillText(fa.get("airplanemode_active"), x, y);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [FontFace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace) interface.

All it needs is the url of your font file. Its `load()` method will return a Promise resolving when the font will be ready to use.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const material_font = new FontFace( 'material-icons',
  // pass the url to the file in CSS url() notation
  'url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v48/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2)' );
document.fonts.add( material_font ); // add it to the document's FontFaceSet

const framework7_font = new FontFace( 'framework7-icons',
  'url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/framework7io/framework7-icons@master/fonts/Framework7Icons-Regular.woff2)' );
document.fonts.add( framework7_font );

// wait the font loads
material_font.load().then( () => {
  // we're good to use it
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.font = '20px material-icons';
  ctx.fillText('airplanemode_active', 20, 40);
}).catch( console.error );

framework7_font.load().then( () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.font = '20px framework7-icons';
  ctx.fillText('airplane', 20, 80);
}).catch( console.error );
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help, but it says this is an experimental technology? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace

Comment: Support is not that bad: [91%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=font-loading) If you need to support older browsers like IE, then you can use libraries that do provide similar APIs, e.g https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver

Comment: if we load the fonts previously on the page, does it need to load again to be rendered inside a canvas element?

Comment: Also why did you choose the `woff2` instead of the TTF file or other font files typically listed with icon fonts?

Comment: If the font is displayed then the browser will already have loaded it, so the promise will resolve immediately, however, having the @font-face doesn't mean it will get loaded, you must have a rendered HTML element using this font so the browser loads it. And I chose woff2 because it's the best format format for web-fonts.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. very helpful. just curious if this means we can skip the font-face interface as long as we ensure the browser has already rendered HTML elements with the icon font?

Comment: Yes, but the FontFace API is actually the only bullet-proof way of knowing it programmatically.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to make the font/icon size a percentage of its container? The goal is to treat the text like an image icon and have it scale in size based on its container. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't load external links, so I'm trying to load the *.woff2 file locally. Do you know how to load it? new FontFace( 'material-icons', url('THE_LOCAL_FILE.woff2')